# Bluetooth on Windows 10, disable Personal Area Netwok (PAN) profile

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10

On Windows 10 when I turn on Bluetooth I have 5 different Bluetooth profiles enabled by default.

- A2DP
- AVRCP
- PAN
- Unknown Service
- HFP

How do I disable these profiles?
I want to disable it because I'm about to start my own profiles programmatically and not let windows 10 interfere.

I have managed to find out what windows services are responsible for bringing up these profiles except the PAN profile. Which obviously is not started from windows service.

Windows services for other profiles are :

- Connected Devices Platform Service
- Bluetooth Audio Gateway Service
- Avctp Service

This is how to check which profiles are on:
You check it from other devices (such as smartphones) via the app.

Question :
How do I disable PAN profile?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb870603(v=vs.85)

Comment: I got it another way, this API was giving me errors.